# Passing value to an input in hidden?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi all I have difficulty of passing value from live search in which the value of the search displayed on page via ul tag. the live search works fine.

this is my database query.(insertdemo.php)

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'thartpc');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'hospital');

if (!$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)) {
die($db->connect_errno.' - '.$db->connect_error);
}

$arr = array();

if (!empty($_POST['keywords'])) {
$keywords = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
$sql = "SELECT id, patientid, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM patient WHERE lastname LIKE '%".$keywords."%'";
$result = $db->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $arr[] = array('id' => $obj->id, 'patientid' => $obj->patientid, 'lastname' => $obj->lastname,'firstname' => $obj->firstname, 'middlename' => $obj->middlename);
    }
}
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

ajax and jquery code (index.php)

I just want to pass the patientid value to an input like this<. input type="hidden" id="pid" name="pid" value="$pid">

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').on('input', function() {
        var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
        if (searchKeyword.length >= 1) {
            $.post('insertdemo.php', { keywords: searchKeyword },   function(data) {
                $('ul#content').empty()
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $('ul#content').append('<li><a href="inserting.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.patientid + ' ' + this.lastname + ' ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.middlename + '</a></li>');
                });
            }, "json");
        }
    });
    });
   </script>
```

html part

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color:#2B547E; border- color:#2B547E">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="container">                         
<div class="col-md-6" style="width:400px; padding-left:0px">    
<form role="form" method="POST"> 
<div class="btn-group btn-group" style="margin-left:0px" role="group" aria-label="...">
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Pharmacy  Portal</button>
</div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">         
                            <input type="text" id="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Patient ID">
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">         
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="height:34px; width:60px ;color:#2B547E " name="submit" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </form>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right" style="padding-right:0px"> 
                <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group">
                        <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
          <span class="icon-bars-button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Patient</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Billing</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php $pid = ''; ?>
<div class="container">
    <ul id="content"></ul>
    <input type="text" name="pid" id="pid" class="form-control" value="<?php "$pid" ?>">

</div>
```

Comment: You want to store `patientid` in hidden field when it will be selected?

Comment: where is that $pid from?

Comment: yes, when the search display is only one item the patientid will be stored automatically to the hidden input or to a variable like $pid even without selecting it.

Comment: $pid, is supposed to be my variable for patientid.

Comment: i have added html part of my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').on('input', function() {
        var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
        if (searchKeyword.length >= 1) {
            $.post('insertdemo.php', { keywords: searchKeyword },   function(data) {
                $('ul#content').empty();
                if (data.length == 1)
                    $('#pid')
                        .val(data[0].patientid);
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $('ul#content').append('<li><a href="inserting.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.patientid + ' ' + this.lastname + ' ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.middlename + '</a></li>');
                });
            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what i mean is theres no refreshing of page will be happening or clicking a button. when the display is only one item the value for patientid will be stored also to the input value?

Comment: @Romeo when it is GT 1?

Comment: when the user type single text on the search something will be displayed already

Comment: what i want to get is when the display of the search is only one the patientid of that display item at the same time. will be pass/displayed also on the input value.

Comment: still not working, when the display is only one the input is empty.

Comment: i have added html part of my page

Comment: @begginer am sorry, you put a "patentid" i discover that very late, hehehe. thanks a lot. it works now.

Comment: can ask you question further?

Comment: if the value im passing to is on the label not on input? what should it be like? i tried this  $('label#content5') or $('ul#content5'), its not working.

Comment: if the value im passing to is on the label not on input? what should it be like? i tried this $('label#content5') or $('ul#content5'), $('$content5'), it's not working.

Comment: @Romeo Check this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90718/discussion-between-beginner-and-romeo).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your html part

`<input type="hidden" id="pid" name="pid" value=""/>`

And in Jquery, update that hidden value

```
$("#pid").val(patientid);
```

Comment: i tried to insert this somwhere on the script but nothing is displayed on input.

Comment: can you post  your html part?

Comment: i have added html part of my page